# What is the difference between filetype= and syntax= in Vim?

Tags: vim, syntax, file-type

I noticed that in order for Vim to color highlight the syntax of a specific file, one can both set the following in the _vimrc file:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.file_extension set filetype=program_highlighting

au BufNewFile,BufRead *.file_extension set syntax=program_highlighting
```

What is the difference between using `filetype=` or `syntax=`?

Answer (score 13):

**The `'filetype'` is a superset of `'syntax'`.**

With `'filetype'` (assuming you have `:filetype plugin on` configured), you also load *filetype plugins* and their corresponding settings (e.g. indent config, compiler, mappings) from the `ftplugin` configuration subdir, in addition to setting the syntax to the filetype name.

That last part is done automatically by Vim as part of the filetype processing, in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/syntax.vim`:

```
au! FileType *  exe "set syntax=" . expand("<amatch>")
```